# Equating 2 objects from different classes in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following classes as given below:

```
//File Name: A.cpp
 class A{
   struct L{
       uint64_t r;
       std::vector < std::pair < std::pair < uint64_t, uint64_t> , std::vector <uint64_t> > > c;
   };
   std::tr1::unordered_map< uint64_t ,L> m;   
};

//File Name: B.cpp
class A;
class B{
   struct L{
       uint64_t r;
       std::vector < std::pair < std::pair < uint64_t, uint64_t >, std::vector <uint64_t > > > c;
   };
   std::tr1::unordered_map< uint64_t , L> m;
public:
   void equateMaps(std::tr1::unordered_map< uint64_t , L> m){
       this->m=m;
   }
};

//File main.cpp
main()
{
    B b; 
    A a
    b.equateMaps(a.m);
}
```

But when I do so I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘b::equateMaps(std::tr1::unordered_map<long unsigned int, A::L>&)’
```

I am not able to get as to why am I getting this error? Can someone please help find out where am I going wrong?

I am using g++ compiler in Ubuntu

Comment: You have two different types, `A::L` and `B::L`, and two different types of map. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok..but is there some way by which I may achieve the same

Comment: Define one single `L` class and use it in `A` and `B`?

Comment: @JannatArora I'm wondering what you're **really** trying to achieve here..

Comment: @lethal-guitar Just trying to pass values between classes

Comment: @lethal-guitar Just trying to pass pointer to an in-memory data structure 'm' between classes

Comment: This behaviour is by design. One of the most basic purposes of classes is to "contain" (i.e. "have" and "prevent global visibility of") names. That is, classes are (with a grain of salt) also namespaces. A and B may be developed by different people in different locations at different times. The implementor of A may not know B. It would easily lead to conflicts if names in different classes were globally visible and even worse if definitions in one class would change the meaning of definitions (or just declarations!) in other classes, e.g. that of a type L.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Ok...I got it..thanks for explaining so well...but I want to pass pointer of this map(which contains about 1 million items) from class A to class B...is there some to achieve the same...as otherwise blind copying will take a lot of time

Comment: That is a totally different question.

Comment: @JannatArora what prevents you from defining the map/data structure outside of your class? Especially if both classes depend on it?

Comment: I think @lethal-guitar's answer provides the solution: If you want a common name L, declare it in the common namespace, which is the global one here. In order to avoid copying you could declare your function `void equateMaps(std::tr1::unordered_map< uint64_t , L> &m)`, i.e. pass a ref, or alternatively a pointer, to the map.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry about that...probably i m bad at framing questions..can u please help...now that u have understood my question

Comment: @PeterSchneider I think your suggestion is awesome...but i m not getting how should I create a pointer to unordered_map. I am a bit weak with pointers..can u please help in this a bit

Comment: Just use a reference in like the prototype I showed above (the only difference in the function parameter declaration is the "&"). The calling code stays as it is. Of course if equate_map() modifies the passed map m it will then actually modify the caller's map. If that's not desired you _have_ to copy, don't you? If, by contrast, it does not change the passed map then you should actually make that explicit and declare the function `void equateMaps(const std::tr1::unordered_map< uint64_t , L> &m)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually intended `struct L` to be the same type, you have to move it out of the class declarations, put it in a separate header, and then include that for both classes:

```
// In a separate header
struct L{
       uint64_t r;
       std::vector < std::pair < std::pair < uint64_t, uint64_t> , std::vector <uint64_t> > > c;
};

// In header for A
#include "l.h"

class A {
    std::tr1::unordered_map< uint64_t ,L> m; 
};

// Similar for B...
```

As you currently have it, `A::L` and `B::L` are completely unrelated types, even thought they look the same. So the corresponding maps are also of different type, and they cannot be compared.